# How to cosmetically remove Index.html from URL with IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

We have a maintenance ASP.NET MVC Site we deploy to a maintenance deployment slot in Azure for fast swaps. Right now the site is static html + a line in Global.asax that tries to redirect all requests to Index.html

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("/Index.html");
    }
```

Now it works but the user sees Index.html in the url when redirected to a maintenance page. I'd like to cosmetically remove it via IIS Url Rewrite rule. How can this be achieved with "Rewrite" action, I assume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it in different ways:

1. With `rewritepath` in global.asax. You can find more details here: https://www.dotnetperls.com/rewritepath
2. With IIS URL Rewrite module. You need to [install it](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) and then in your web.config add this rewrite rule:

   `<rule name="Rewrite index.html" stopProcessing="true">
       <match url="(.*)" />
       <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
   </rule>`
   This rule will rewrite all requests to your `index.html`